# ReactNative app works on android and ios, i enabled ipad support from xcode, but when i run on ipad, the view looks fine, but touch doesnt work

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, mobile, development-environment

My reactnative app is loading but touch is not working on IPAD.
Works perfect on iphone/android.

I have made the app universal, now the app loads perfectly on ipad but touch doesnt worlk.
I even removed all code and added just a button, that is also not clickable.
I updated reactnative version, reanimated version and gesture library version.
Still stuck.